# SSRS Report format not displaying as expected

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I've created a report using two separate datasets. One dataset includes monthly summary data (counts, dollars, etc.) The other contains quarterly data. I'm tring to display both the monthly and quarterly data on the same page. I created a rectangle and dragged both tablix(s) inside with the quarterly tablix positioned below the monthly. When the report is rendered, The first two pages will show just the monthly data (one page for each client). The third page will show the monthly for the third client plus the quarterly for the first client. The last 2 pages will each show the quarterly data for the two remaining clients.

If I change the layout in design mode and position the quarterly tablix to the right of the monthly one, the report renders as expected showing the monthly and quarterly data for each client. The report should be a total of 3 pages with each page showing monthly and quarterly data for the three client groupings I have.

I'm not sure why I can't get the data to display correctly when the second tablix is positioned below the first. I've tried creating additional rectangles and dragging each individual tablix inside their own rectangle and then dragging both of those inside a third rectangle. (I feel like this is overkill though!)

I've also checked the 'display on one page is possible' options but that doesn't seem to help either.

Any suggestions that can be provided would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add pictures? I'm not seeing what you're saying. You say you added rectangles around some tables but a table/tablix needs to be dragged **into** a rectangle after the rectangle is created.

Comment: Tablixes expand their height to fit the number of data rows provided.  Can you stick with your side-by-side solution?

Answer (score 0):

amalgamate your datasets into a single dataset.

then you only need one tablix.
format it so that the monthly data and the quarterly data are grouped appropriately, then group the whole thing by client.
putting in a page break between instances of the client group will put each clients data (both monthly and quarterly) on a new page.